# How make the same Android application but with different icon e colors in a clean way

Tags: android, architecture, duplicates, project

I have this needs.

I have developed an app and I want to duplicate it. I can copy and paste the project but if I do this 10 times can be a problem. The problem is, if I found a bug in the 10th duplicate, I have to review all other projects and I don't want to do this.

There is a clean way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using Android Studio and/or gradle? This sounds like the perfect use case for `productFlavors`. Among other things, different product flavors can point to different source directories. In this case, your app's `build.gradle` (**NOT** your project's top level `build.gradle`) might look like this:

```
android {
    ... other android stuff ...
    productFlavors {
        firstapp {
        ... other configuration. e.g. applicationId, minifyEnabled, etc ...
        }
        secondapp {
        ... other configuration. e.g. applicationId, minifyEnabled, etc ...
        }
    }
}
```

In order to enable different icons, you'd want to include 2 extra src folders (siblings to you `main` directory): `/firstapp` and `/secondapp`. The only thing that you need add to each of these directories is your icon, one color in each.

In Android, since you icons usually live in the `drawable-x` directories, your directory structure will look something like this:

`/src
   /main
      ... all your normal source code ...
   /firstapp
      /res
         /drawable-xhdpi
             my_icon.png 
   /secondapp
      /res
         /drawable-xhdpi
             my_icon.png`

Notice that the icons take the same name. It's up to you to change the color.

The last step is building your app. When you want the first icon, you'll build first app (something like `./gradlew assembleFirstappRelease`). When you want to second icon, you'll build the second app (something like `./gradlew assembleSecondappRelease`).

Comment: Ok. Maybe the question is not clean. I want to decouple "n" application with the same core. For example I want an application that download an object with id=1 and another application download an object with id=2. The presentation of the application is the same except form the color and icon.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'd recommend exactly the same thing, except that `/drawable/my_icon.png` changes to a `integers.xml` file in your `/values` directory. Then you'll have an integer called `object_id` that equals 1 in `firstapp` and 2 in `secondapp`. When it comes time in you app code to download that resource in your source code, just reference that integer like so: `Fragment.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.object_id);`